# CSS Box-Shadow div overlay

Tags: html, overlay, z-index, css

I have a problem with a box-shadow, being obscured by another div.

Here is my code:

HTML-

```
<div id="wrap">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="nav"></div>
        </div>  
        <div id="main_content"></div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS-

```
body{
    margin:0;
}
#wrap{
    margin:0 auto;

    width:84%;
}
#header{    
    background-image:url(img/header_pattern.png);
    background-repeat:repeat;

    margin:0 auto;

    width:100%;
    height:170px;

    box-shadow:5px 5px 5px black;
    z-index:1;
}
#main_content{
    background-image:url(img/main_pattern.png);
    background-repeat:repeat;

    width:100%;
    min-height:700px;
    height:100%;
    z-index:2;

}
```

Screenshot-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfDyi.png

How can I make it so that the shadow is not "stacked under" (on the z-axis), and hence obscured by, the `#main_content` div, but still inside my `#wrap`?

Thanks.

No, I don't just wan't to push the `#main_content` down.

Comment: have a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-shadow :)

Answer (score 7):

Just add:

```
position: relative;
```

To `#header{`

**Example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/kJajC/

Answer (score 0):

You need to "position" an element, if you want to "stack" it differently on the z-axis using `z-index`.

Note that if you don't actually want to change its position on the x/y plane, then just specify that it is `position:relative;` without any of the `top`, `bottom`, `left` or `right` x/y offsets and it'll be positioned on the x/y plane where it would've been laid down statically anyway.

From [MDN on adding a z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index/Adding_z-index):

> Warning! z-index only has an effect if an element is positioned.

I found their series of articles [Understanding CSS z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index) really helpful with this stuff.